# Filter a Pandas dataframe if cell values exist in another dataframe but with a range

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrame, with the same structure. Dataframe B is a subset of DataFrame A.

I want to filter DataFrame B, only if the Price value appears in DataFrame A, **or it is within 1% of a value in DataFrame A**.

For example, even if the exact price is not present, I want to keep the value if there is a row in A with a price +/- 1%.

DataFrame A:

```
index  price
    0  20.23
    1  10.34
    2  5.28
    3  12.25
    4  12.32
```

DataFrame B:

```
index  price
    0  0.23
    1  10.34
    2  5.26
```

Desired Result of filtering:

```
index  price
    0  10.34
    1  5.26
```

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'price': [20.23, 10.34, 5.28, 12.25, 12.32]})

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 1, 2],
        'price': [0.23, 10.34, 5.26]})
```

The following will only give me the exact matches.

```
dfB[dfB['price'].isin(dfA['price'])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another take, using `.merge_asof` (note: `dfA` and `dfB` needs to  be sorted by `price`):

```py
dfA = dfA.sort_values("price")
dfB = dfB.sort_values("price")

x = pd.merge_asof(dfB, dfA, on="price", direction="nearest")
```

Creates `x`:

```
   index_x  price  index_y
0        0   0.23        2
1        2   5.26        2
2        1  10.34        1
```

---

Then calculating the percentage difference:

```py
x["diff"] = np.abs(x["price"] - dfA.loc[x["index_y"], "price"].values)
print(x[x["diff"] <= (x["price"] / 100)])
```

Prints:

```
   index_x  price  index_y  diff
1        2   5.26        2  0.02
2        1  10.34        1  0.00
```

---

The complete code:

```py
dfA = dfA.sort_values("price")
dfB = dfB.sort_values("price")

x = pd.merge_asof(dfB, dfA, on="price", direction="nearest")
x["diff"] = np.abs(x["price"] - dfA.loc[x["index_y"], "price"].values)
x = x[x["diff"] <= (x["price"] / 100)]

x = x[["index_x", "price"]].set_index("index_x").rename_axis(index=None).sort_index()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   price
1  10.34
2   5.26
```

Comment: Damn I just added a `merge_asof` alternative hadn't seen yours

Comment: Can you explain how the diff of each row with all the other rows is calculated? I need to understand how you filter out DF values if they are within a percentage of values in other rows of the column (similar values).

Comment: @cksrc For example, diff between `5.28` and `5.26` is `0.02`. `1%` of `5.26` is `5.26 / 100`. So you need to compare if `0.02 <= 5.26 / 100`, which is `0.02 <= 0.0526` which is `True` - so we keep the value.

Comment: where does "index_y" come from?

Comment: @cksrc `index_y` comes from the `.merge_asof` function

Answer (score 3):

Using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting to compare the combinations of prices and determine if [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) is within 1%:

```
a = dfA['price'].to_numpy()[:, None]
b = dfB['price'].to_numpy()

out = dfA[(abs(a-b)/a<0.01).any(axis=1)]
```

Alternatively, using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), which might be more efficient on large datasets:

```
keep = (pd
   .merge_asof(dfA['price'].sort_values().reset_index(),
               dfB['price'].sort_values().rename('ref'),
               left_on='price', right_on='ref'
              )
   .loc[lambda d: abs(d['price']-d['ref'])/d['price'] < 0.01]
   ['index']
)

out = dfA.loc[keep]
```

Output:

```
   index  price
1      1  10.34
2      2   5.28
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us use broadcasting to calculate the percent difference between dfB and dfA price then filter the rows where the absolute difference is within 1%

```
diff = 1 - dfA['price'].values / dfB['price'].values[:, None]
mask = np.any(abs(diff) <= 0.01, axis=1)

dfB[mask]
```

---

```
   index  price
1      1  10.34
2      2   5.26
```

Answer (score 1):

One efficient option is with [pyjanitor's conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(dfA
.assign(
    start=dfA.price.mul(0.99), 
    end=dfA.price.mul(1.01)
   )
.conditional_join(
    dfB, 
   ('start', 'price', '<='), 
   ('end', 'price', '>='), 
   right_columns=['index', 'price'], 
   df_columns=None)
) 
   index  price
0      1  10.34
1      2   5.26
```

Comment: Efficient, except if you have many matches, that would duplicate the rows right?

Comment: I missed that part, OP wants just a single match? I couldn't glean that from d question

Comment: OP wants some kind of `isin` with tolerance ;)