# Find how many times a DataFrame cell value appears in another DataFrame, with a tolerance

Tags: python, pandas

Given two DataFrames with the same columns.

dfA

```
Index Price
0     10.21
1     12.21
```

dfB

```
Index Price
0     10.21
1     10.24
2     11.32
3     12.21
```

I want to add a column to dfA with the times that each value appears in dfB, but with a tolerance of, let's say, 1%.

Result

```
Index Price Occurrences 
0     10.21 2
1     12.21 1
```

Is it still possible to avoid iterations? Maybe using `merge_asof` and `grouping`?

P.S. This is an amendment to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77045763/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-if-cell-values-exist-in-another-dataframe-but-with-a-r/77045897?noredirect=1#comment135838786_77045897), but posted in a different threat since it addresses a slightly different issue.

Comment: Can a number be counted for 2 prices of dfA if it is close enough to both?

Comment: @mozway Yes, it should

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter a Pandas dataframe if cell values exist in another dataframe but with a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77045763/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-if-cell-values-exist-in-another-dataframe-but-with-a-r)

Comment: You cannot use `merge_asof` here as if would enable only a single match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to test all combinations, use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting:

```
a = dfA['Price'].to_numpy()[:,None]
b = dfB['Price'].to_numpy()

dfA['Occurrences'] = (abs(a-b) < a*0.01).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Index  Price  Occurrences
0      0  10.21            2
1      1  12.21            1
```

Intermediates:

```
# abs(a-b)
array([[0.  , 0.03, 1.11, 2.  ],
       [2.  , 1.97, 0.89, 0.  ]])

# (abs(a-b) < a*0.01)
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway, I just ran your code and I get Occurrences 1 for both. How does abs(a-b) < a*0.01 calculate percentage differences? Also, for numpy broadcasting what is the logic on the way we structure the arrays, to_numpy()[:,None] vs to_numpy()

Comment: Can you provide reproducible inputs

Comment: `import pandas as pd
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'Price': pd.Series([10.21, 12.21])})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'Price': pd.Series([10.21, 10,22, 11.32, 12.21])})

a = dfA['Price'].to_numpy()[:,None]
b = dfB['Price'].to_numpy()

dfA['Occurrences'] = (abs(a-b) < a*0.01).sum(axis=1)

print(dfA)`

Comment: @cksrc your data here is different from the sample data. `10,22` vs `10.22`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an explanation of the accepted answer which is brilliant but might be difficult for some people to understand.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
#initial DataFrame
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'Price': pd.Series([10.21, 12.21])}) 
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'Price': pd.Series([10.21, 10.22, 11.32, 12.21])})  
#convert to numpy arrays
#shape of 'a' is 2 rows zero columns (2,)
a = dfA['Price'].to_numpy()
#shape of 'b' is 4 rows zero columns (4,)
b = dfB['Price'].to_numpy() 
#we wish to compare each value of 'a' with each value of 'b'
#this can be achieved by numpy array broadcasting, with a stretch
```

[image: numpy broadcasting stretch]

```
#Convert the (2,) array to (2,1) in order to enable stretching 
a=a[:,np.newaxis]
#the absolute difference of every element of 'a' subtracted by every 
element of 'b'
#the result is a (2,4) matrix
c = abs(a-b)
print(c)
print(c.shape)

#which is not the same as the percentage difference: abs(a-b)/((a+b)/2)
d = (abs(a-b))/((a+b)/2)
print(d)

#finally, we assign a new column to our initial DataFrame, that counts the values
#with percentage difference greater than 0.01 (1%)
dfA['Occurrences'] = (d < 0.01).sum(axis=1)  
print(dfA)
```

Output

```
[[0.   0.01 1.11 2.  ]
 [2.   1.99 0.89 0.  ]]
(2, 4)
[[0.         0.00097895 0.10311194 0.17841213]
 [0.17841213 0.17744093 0.07564811 0.        ]]
   Price  Occurrences
0  10.21            2
1  12.21            1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge_asof`, which avoids the risk of memory explode due to broadcasting, then thresholding by the ratios, and count the values:

```
(pd.merge_asof(dfB.sort_values('Price'),
              dfA.sort_values('Price').rename(columns={'Price':'target'}),
              left_on='Price', right_on='target', direction='nearest'
             )
   .loc[lambda x: x['Price'].sub(x['target']).abs().div(x['target']).le(0.01)]
   ['target'].value_counts()
 )
```

Output:

```
10.21    2
12.21    1
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

Comment: As I described in comments you can't use `merge_asof` because OP wants a many-to-many mapping. All combinations are required.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0, 1], 'Price': [10.21, 12.21]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'Price': [10.21, 10.24, 11.32, 12.21]})
"""
print(df_a)
print(df_b)
   Index  Price
0      0  10.21
1      1  12.21
   Index  Price
0      0  10.21
1      1  10.24
2      2  11.32
3      3  12.21"""

price_a = df_a['Price'].to_numpy()[:, None]
"""print(price_a)
[[10.21]
 [12.21]]"""
price_b = df_b['Price'].to_numpy()
"""print(price_b)
[10.21 10.24 11.32 12.21]"""
# Calculate absolute differences and identify matching prices within tolerance
tol_range = (1 - 0.01) * price_a, (1 + 0.01) * price_a
"""print(tol_range)
(array([[10.1079],
       [12.0879]]), array([[10.3121],
       [12.3321]]))"""
price_mask = (price_b >= tol_range[0]) & (price_b <= tol_range[1])
print(price_mask)
"""print(df_a[price_mask])
   Index  Price
0      0  10.21
0      0  10.21
1      1  12.21"""
# Count occurrences for each price in df_a 
occurrences = price_mask.sum(axis=1)

df_a['Occurrences'] = occurrences

"""print(df_a)
   Index  Price  Occurrences
0      0  10.21            2
1      1  12.21            1"""
```